# Simulating/data harvesting n-body coulomb interactions

Tags: python, particle-system

Are there any coulomb interaction n-body simulator packages where my inputs would just be initial positions, mass, charge, and velocity and outputs would be the values of the inputs after some dt?

If there is not, how would I go about efficiently developing one in python for many bodies (200+ charged entities)?

I know that this is the structure, but I am confused as to what I put in the middle:

```
 #set values to initial positions, velocities, mass, and charges
 for dt in range(T):
     for p in range(len(positions)):
         ?
```

Do I calculate EVERY other particle-interaction in the system or just nearby ones. If the latter, what is considered as “nearby” and what would I input into the “?” function wise?

Just so you know, I have looked for 2D simulation repositories, but almost ALL are for gravity-based simulations (the ones for coulomb interactions are limited to 2 and 3 bodies). Therefore, any guidance with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem with calculating N-body interactions is that they can get _really big_ really fast. You need to calculate the force of _each body_ on _every other body_ and calculate their accelerations due to the net force. Then you can advance the timestep by calculating the displacement due to that acceleration.

Comment: The specifics of if/how you will prioritize which forces to calculate are off-topic for StackOverflow. As is the answer to _"what would I input into the ? function wise"_, because we can answer _specific programming questions_ but will not write your code for you.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi How can I make the process more efficient? The only way I can imagine doing this is with a triple for loop (for time, then the position of every single particle, and then the last one for its interaction with every other particle. Is there a way to do this in less than O(n3) time?

Comment: Look into vectorization leveraging SIMD instructions. You can use numpy in Python compiled with a BLAS implementation, but it is going to be computationally intensive either way -- no getting around that.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Ok I’ll look into that thanks!